# Birchas Ilanos at night

Tags: blessing, trees, evening-night

Can you make Birchas Ilanos at night? (sources)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Tzitz Eliezer 12:20-6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14511&st=&pgnum=66) you may say the Bracha at night so long you can properly discern the tree.